# Использование плагина twentytwenty в wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть ли возможность в плагине twentytwenty для WP устанавливать настройки к примеру:

> ```
> before_label: 'До',  
> after_label: 'После'
> ```

```
[twentytwenty]
<img src="https://images.wallpaperscraft.ru/image/doroga_derevia_razmetka_121714_1024x768.jpg" />
<img src="https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/44/84/WGN0ne.jpg" />
[/twentytwenty]
```

Comment: Что за плагин такой? twentytwenty это тема. https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwenty/. И конкретизируй вопрос. Что именно хочешь реализовать, для чего.

Comment: К сожалению не знал что есть еще тема, [ссылка](https://wordpress.org/plugins/twentytwenty/) на плагин, он позволяет делать наложение двух фото друг на друга и слайдером можно управлять какое из фото будет видно, по умолчанию по краям фото есть надписи "before" и "after", я хочу их заменить на свои.

Comment: А не смутило "Last updated:5 years ago"?